# MySQL auto_increments always insert 2147483647

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I have the following SQL code in PHP

```
    $conn->query("INSERT INTO orders (Name,Email,phone) VALUES 
    ('$name','$email','$phone')");
```

my database table has id,Name,Email,phone

insertion is successful but the id is always set to 2147483647 which is the max int(11)

so there is only one row in my table

ID-------------Name------- Email-------phone

2147483647--John--Smith--John@John.com--04524524

the id field is set as autoincrement

instead of being 1 or 2 it goe all the way to max (2147483647)

even if i make BIGINT or change the type mysql will insert the max ID increment

Comment: can you post the table structure using : mysql>    desc orders;

Comment: To OP: Please mind that your PHP code is vulnerable to SQL injection if the variables (`$name`, `$email`, `$phone`) come from an input.

Answer (score 2):

You can reset the counter with:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename AUTO_INCREMENT = 1
```

For InnoDB you cannot set the `auto_increment` value lower or equal to the highest current index. (quote from [ViralPatel][1]):

> Note that you cannot reset the counter to a value less than or equal
>   to any that have already been used. For MyISAM, if the value is less
>   than or equal to the maximum value currently in the AUTO_INCREMENT
>   column, the value is reset to the current maximum plus one. For
>   InnoDB, if the value is less than the current maximum value in the
>   column, no error occurs and the current sequence value is not changed.

If you are just bootstrapping your database, you maybe should consider emptying the table using:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename;
```

The command above will also reset any automatic counters.

Answer (score 0):

I have duplicate the table, data and structure,then delete the original one.
then rename table to replace, and voilá...
Autoinsert is OK